# 404 page title SEOmatic

Tags: craft3, plugin-seomatic, 404-page

404 page doesn't have a title. It shows "| Sitename" in my case.

I'm using Craft 3 with the [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic) plugin and would like to set the title in the 404 template.

```
{% set seomaticMeta = seomaticMeta | merge({ seoTitle: '404 page not found' }) %}
```

This gives a internal server error, looks like the seomaticMeta object is not available on the 404 page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like you're using the old syntax for SEOmatic 1.x for Craft 2.x; here's how you do the same thing in SEOmatic for Craft 3:

```
{% do seomatic.meta.seoTitle("Some Title") %}
```

c.f.: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic#twig-templating

Comment: sorry about that I was using the old syntax

Comment: actually this doesn't work for a 404.twig in the templates folder

Comment: Are you sure? I'm setting it that way here: https://nystudio107.com/404

Comment: Looks like the title is only updating after save some Seomatic settings page.

Comment: @Jeroen Saving a settings page clears the caches. So it sounds like you're making Twig templating changes in an environment with `devMode` off, or you're not clearly caches on deploy.

Comment: Hi @andrew.welch I know this is an old question but it appears there is something still strange going on with a 404 page title. In the instance of a 404, seomatic.meta.seoTitle can end up with a value even though entry is not defined and its not been manually set.

You can see it here is different to your 404 page example: https://nystudio107.com/404test